# How do I iterate over a nested list, where nodes may be missing

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr, tibble

I am constructing a data frame from a (very deeply nested) json source.

I have successfully mapped the list elements I want to extract, and can almost! construct the tibble I want.

Except that some of the list elements are missing, if there is no data. Like so (I want the `chr` at position `"five"`, and `NA` if it is missing, like in the second list):

```
nested_list  <- list(
    list(
        x = list(one = "this"),
        y = list(two = list(
                     three = list(
                           four = data_frame(
                                five = "is"))))),
   list(
       x = list(one = "a"),
       y = list(two = list(three = list()))))
```

How can I supply a fallback if the outer elements are missing? I'm fumbling around with `map_if`, but can't figure out a predicate function to test for presence of an element. I get

```
Error: Predicate functions must return a single `TRUE` or `FALSE`, not NULL
```

so far.

I think I have a reproducible example:

```
library("tidyverse")

nested_list  <- list(
    list(
        x = list(one = "this"),
        y = list(two = list(
                       three = list(
                               four = data_frame(
                                      five = "is"))))),
   list(
       x = list(one = "a"),
       y = list(two = list(three = list()))))

test_df <- nested_list %>%
    map(~ .x) %>%
    tibble(
        one = map_chr(., c("x", "one")),
        three = map_chr(., c("y", "two", "three", "four", "five"))
   )
```

this returns

```
Error: Result 2 must be a single string, not NULL of length 0
```

Where I'd like to just have a missing value in my final tibble.

reducing the tibble constructor to

```
test_df <- nested_list %>%
    map(~ .x) %>%
    tibble(
        one = map_chr(., c("x", "one")),
        three = map(., c("y", "two", "three"))
   )
```

gives me NULL values in the second row of the data frame; and, as expected, a nested list in the first row. `map_df(., c("one","two", "three", "four")) gives me uneven columns, and the tibble construction fails.

And my google fu is failing me.

Comment: you need to make this reproducible. please include a sample of your data, what you have tried and that the desired output is. It is very hard to help you with so little information

Comment: yes. sorry about that - I've attempted to produce an example, but seem to be flailing about a bit in reproducing the wonky list in question.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1krPtBND-anusscZ5fRT3M5SwP8MMlO49 for my data file to pass in as jsondata

Comment: @RAB finally figured out a reproducible example, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suspected, I was holding it wrong. There is a `.null` parameter to map, for just this purpose.

So:

```
test_df <- nested_list %>%
map(~ .x) %>%
tibble(
    one = map_chr(., c("x", "one")),
    three = map_chr(., c("y", "two", "three", "four", "five"), .null = NA_character_)
)
```

Works as expected.